# VS 2012 does not load connections from package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, ssis

I have an SSIS package that was developed by someone else on their PC. We both have VS2012. When I try to load the package (from the TFS local folder) the connections dont come along with the package. As soon as the package opens, it throws an expected error message that "It had errors while trying to load the package". I dont see any connection managers in the Connection Manager pane.

Has someone come across the same situation? This is just so painful to debug given that its the same environment. Maybe some checkin issues or something? Please advise.

Comment: What **version** of SSIS is the package?

Comment: have a look at the other persons solution and ensure that everything is checked into source control, check that the connections have the source control icons next to them.